# Encoding String read in xml (IOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an audio player, and I made an xml file that is downloaded to the startup app containing the url of the streaming, so if you have any alteration in the streaming server ip is not I change the xml without having to update the app,

path of the xml: http://xxxx.com.br/data_streamer/data_streaming.php

the xml is downloaded and read the path correctly, but does not initialize the streaming seems to be something with the codification of the string, but not sure, the fact is that if I manually put the address (@"http://184.107.211.74:8090") with the Parser is exactly the same.

XML parser (I show only the part that reads the tag);

```
- (Void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement: (NSString *) elementName
  namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) qname
    attributes: (NSDictionary *) {attributeDict
    if (qname) {
        QName elementName =;
    }
    if (elementName) {
        current = [NSString stringWithString: elementName];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"url"]) {
    }
}

- (Void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didEndElement: (NSString *) elementName
  namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) {QName
if ([current isEqualToString:@"url"]) {
        [Outstring AppendFormat:@"%@",@"\n"];
    }

current = nil;
}

- (Void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters: (NSString *) string {
    if (! current)
        return;
if ([current isEqualToString: @"url"]) {
        [Outstring AppendFormat: @"%@", string];
    }
}
```

Now the code that calls my streaming:

```
- (Void) createStreamer {

    NSLog (@"%@", pathDataString)
    if (streamer)
{
return;
}

[DestroyStreamer self];

NSString * = escapedValue
    [(NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes (
                                                         nil,
                                                         (CFStringRef)pathDataString,
                                                         NULL,
                                                         NULL,
                                                         kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
     autorelease];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: escapedValue];
streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL: url];

}
```

pathDataString contains postoperative day ip server with its contents tested in debug

I do not know what is happening, any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening that is unexpected?   "contains postoperative day ip server with its contents tested in debug" is hard to understand and it's not clear what effect you're getting.  Also, there are spaces between % and @ in multiple places, as well as between \ and n.   Are these in the code or just in the paste here? If in the code, you should remove them, if they are in just the example here, please remove them from the example, for clarity.

Comment: spaces were created on their own when I copied the code over here, the error is relatively simple, I download the xml, read and print the server ip, exactly as in the xml (http://184.107.211.74:8090) that singnifica that there is nothing wrong with reading the xml correct?

However he did not connect with the server, but if I put the ip manually so @ "http://184.107.211.74:8090" it works normally.


in short, works manually, but with the string in the XML Parser not.

Comment: Please sort out the second code fragment.  Apart form the fact that the indentation is all over the place, it couldn't possibly compile due to the syntax errors.  This is nonsense: `[DestroyStreamer self];` sending self to any object returns self and does nothing else.

Comment: http://www.crocko.com/AF9945C44083452DB863C738B87B30B6/sugui-AudioStreamer-e5b6e00.zip

download this design is the same, single difereça that instead of a TextField to get the ip, I'm downloading an xml containing the reboot of the server ip streaming, the code works fine if I manually put the esdereço as already quoted. The XML is being read correctly, and there is not any problem with the code that runs streaming, ip either manually or using the read data in XML is the same, only it does not work (not connected to the server) with the data read from xml.